# Importing JSON to DynamoDB

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

It is my first encounter with DynamoDB and I have been given a JSON File that looks like:

```
{
  "metadata":{
     "schemaVersion":"1.0",
     "importType":"LEX",
     "importFormat":"JSON"
  },
  "resource":{
     "description":"First Names",
     "name":"ASDUKfirstNames",
     "version":"1",
     "enumerationValues":[
     {
        "value":"Zeshan"
     },
     {
        "value":"Zoe"
     },
     {
        "value":"Zul"
     }
  ],
    "valueSelectionStrategy":"ORIGINAL_VALUE"
  }
}
```

and I want to import the data where `value` = `FirstName` in the DynamoDB Table that I have created named `customerDetails` that contains items `CustomerID`, `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Is there a way to utilize the boto3 `put-item` function to loop over the contents of the JSON file replacing `value` with `FirstName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Python to do the data transformation. You can find the boto3 DDB docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html).

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('customerDetails')

json_data = { ... load the data into a dict here ... }

for enumeration_value in json_data['resouce']['enumerationValues']:
  ddb_item = {
    "CustomerID": 123,
    "FirstName": enumeration_value['value']]
  }
  table.put_item(Item=ddb_item)
```

Comment: I want to carry on from this by merging json from another file. The structure is exactly the same as the file I first posted but the file name is `lastNames.json`. Is it possible to extract the `enumerationValue` from each file and append them to create my `ddb_item` in the structure: 
`ddb_item = {
    "CustomerID": (this needs to be an auto-incrementing int),
    "FirstName": enumeration_value['file1_value'], 
    "LastName":enumeration_value['file2_value']
}`

Comment: Please create a new question for this. As far as I know DynamoDB does not provide an auto-increment.